# How to open pdp context(2G, 3G) in the libraries layer without using httpclient directly

Tags: android

I usually make functions used in libraries layer in android.
These day, I need to make new function using http protocol.
So I found httpclient in Java layer.
But I want to know how to open pdp context(2G, 3G) in libraries layer
without using httpclient in java layer directly.

Tthanks in advance
mark.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via the Android SDK -- sorry!